# After changing network openvpn keeps querying stale dns

Tags: fedora, dns, openvpn

After changing network connection in my laptop (fedora 21) openvpn clinet is unable to resolve server address so every several seconds same line appears in logs:

```
RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: vpn.x.y: Name or service not known
```

I've found that openvpn process keeps open udp port 53 connection to old dns server before network provider has changed.

I was trying to add *without success) into client.conf

```
ping 10
ping-restart 60
```

I have few doubts here.

First is that there is no timeout on bind connection?

Second is that I am using dnsmasq and openvpn should use it. However it seems to be NetworkManager problem because I cannot see 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf